# The best way to describe the result of the process of choosing

Tags: phrase-request

I want to make a sentence describing a process of choosing clothes by a girl resulting in making her choice. I am not sure how to do the final part of the sentence:

1. "She spent 5 hours choosing clothing and finally **stopped** at these." - I am afraid that this may imply that she only stopped at these clothes without necessarily choosing them. In other words, the process of choosing was stalled for some other reason.
2. "She spent 5 hours choosing clothing and finally **arrived at** these." - Same problem.
3. "She spent 5 hours **choosing** clothing and finally **chose** these." - I am afraid that repeating the same-root word ("choose") may sound redundant.

So, what's the best way of putting it?

Comment: Selected, arrived at, ended up with...

Comment: An ESL speaker, I'd opted for something like this:  She spent five hours choosing/picking her outfit and finally decided on/opted for these [items].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kate Bunting comment suggested, one way of constructing the sentence is:

> She spent 5 hours selecting what to wear, arrived at these choices, and finally ended up with the dress she wore to the prom last year.

The benefit: it avoids repetition of a root word and describes a concrete process by adding details.

If the details are not available:

> She spent 5 hours choosing clothing and ended up with these.

Another option is as @Victor B commented:

> She spent 5 hours choosing her outfit and finally decided on these.